# jQuery table expander works in Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a Pelican (static site generator) website that converts code in pre tags into line-numbered syntax coloured tables, and I'm trying to add a button to each generated code table to toggle between expanding the table to full size (where a long line causes it to exceed the container) and a size that fits neatly within the container.

I've thrown together some Javascript to do it (not really my forte) and it's working in Chrome, but Firefox doesn't like it (though annoying throws out no console errors).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set code boxes up for expanding
    var site_width = $('.entry-content').width();
    $('table.highlighttable').each(function() {
        // store each code block's width in its tabindex for later retrieval
        $(this).attr('tabindex', $(this).width());
    });
    // initially restrict all code blocks to site width (could be CSS really)
    $('table.highlighttable').css('width', site_width);
    // add button to each code block to expand / collapse
    $('.code pre').append('<a href="#" class="code-expand">&raquo;</a>');
    jQuery(".code-expand").click(function() {
        var natural_width = $(this).closest('table.highlighttable').attr('tabindex');
        var site_width = $('.entry-content').width();
        if($(this).closest('table.highlighttable').width() > site_width) {
            // if code is expanded, collapse code
            $(this).closest('table.highlighttable').css('width', site_width);
            $(this).html('&raquo');
        } else {
            // if code is collapsed, expand code
            $(this).closest('table.highlighttable').css('width', natural_width);
            $(this).html('&laquo');
        }
        return false;
    });
});

<div class="entry-content">
  <table class="highlighttable">
    <tr>
      <td class="code">
        <div class="highlight"><pre>
      stuffstuffstuffstuffstuffstuffstuffstuffstuffstuffstuffstuffstuff
          </pre>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

.entry-content {
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.highlighttable {
  table-layout:fixed;
  border:1px solid #F00;
}
```

Comment: Well I added it to a Codepen and bizarrely it's working in Firefox. So I went through my page removing all other JS and CSS and it still won't work in Firefox!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - it wasn't even a Javascript issue, was CSS. I'm using Bootstrap and that sets tables at max-width of 100%. Chrome it seems is happy to override that but Firefox won't unless you override max-width in the CSS.